# How to drop duplicates from a subset of rows in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
A   B       C
12  true    1
12  true    1
3   nan     2
3   nan     3
```

I would like to drop all rows where the value of column A is duplicate but only if the value of column B is 'true'.

The resulting dataframe I have in mind is:

```
A   B       C
12  true    1
3   nan     2
3   nan     3
```

I tried using: `df.loc[df['B']=='true'].drop_duplicates('A', inplace=True, keep='first')` but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can sue `pd.concat` split the df by B

```
df=pd.concat([df.loc[df.B!=True],df.loc[df.B==True].drop_duplicates(['A'],keep='first')]).sort_index()
df

Out[1593]: 
    A     B  C
0  12  True  1
2   3   NaN  2
3   3   NaN  3
```

Answer (score 5):

```
df[df.B.ne(True) | ~df.A.duplicated()]

    A     B  C
0  12  True  1
2   3   NaN  2
3   3   NaN  3
```

Comment: Other way of saying `df[~(df.B & df.A.duplicated())]`

Comment: I always liked that De Morgan guy.  However, tricky bit is that OP has mixed `bool`/`NaN`.  `bool(np.nan)` evaluates to `True` so `df.B.ne(True)` seemed more reasonable.